# Cross-platform encryption/decryption - Handling Keys and Initialization Vectors (IV)

Tags: .net, cross-platform, encryption

After looking through a number of examples I have peiced together some encryption/decryption methods that make use of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to obtain the key and initialization vector. My concern is that the party receiving my encrypted content must be able to decrypt it. Since I have no control over what language they are using (could be Java, PHP, C, etc ..) how do I ensure that they are able to derive the Key and Initialization Vector (IV) as I have using the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class in .NET? Here are the encryption and decryption methods I am using.

```
Public Shared Function EncryptText(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal password As String) As String

  Dim aesCrypto As Rijndael = Nothing
  Dim plainTextBytes As Byte()
  plainTextBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(plainText)

  Dim rfc2898 As Rfc2898DeriveBytes
  rfc2898 = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, GenerateSalt(password))
  aesCrypto = Rijndael.Create()
  aesCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
  Dim tx As ICryptoTransform
  tx = aesCrypto.CreateEncryptor(rfc2898.GetBytes(32), rfc2898.GetBytes(16))
  Dim encryptedBytes As Byte()
  encryptedBytes = tx.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
  Return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes)

End Function

Public Shared Function DecryptText(ByVal encryptedText As String, ByVal password As String) As String

  Dim aesCrypto As Rijndael = Nothing
  Dim encryptedTextBytes As Byte()
  encryptedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText)

  Dim rfc2898 As Rfc2898DeriveBytes
  rfc2898 = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, GenerateSalt(password))
  aesCrypto = Rijndael.Create()
  aesCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
  Dim tx As ICryptoTransform
  tx = aesCrypto.CreateEncryptor(rfc2898.GetBytes(32), rfc2898.GetBytes(16))
  Dim decryptedBytes As Byte()
  decryptedBytes = tx.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.Length)
  Return Encoding.Default.GetString(decryptedBytes)

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would tell the recipient to implement PBKDF2, which is a standard defined in [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) and [PKCS #5](ftp://ftp.rsa.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2-0.pdf).  [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) says that their function uses HMAC-SHA-1 as the pseudorandom function, and 1000 as the default number of iterations.  This is the information they'll need.

However, you will also need to transmit the salt that was created with `GenerateSalt()` on the sending side.  The recipient cannot just call `GenerateSalt()` themselves - it should be randomly generated for each message.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I needed to know. I will send the "salt" along with the encrypted text.